# JSON.Net incorrectly serializes a two dimensional array to a one dimension

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Trying to convert a two dimensional array to a two dimensional JSON.Net array.

Is there something wrong with the code below?  Or just isn't this supported by JSON.Net?

```
        var A = new int[2, 4] { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 } };

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(A));

        // CONSOLE: [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]  
        //
        // NB. displays a one dimensional array 
        // instead of two e.g. [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have the notion of a 2D array in the same sense that C# does. In order to get an array like that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-to-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript), you'll need to create an array of arrays instead.

```
// output: [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]]
var a = new int[][] { new[]{ 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new[]{ 2, 2, 2, 2 } };
```

#### Update:

[It sounds like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11833103/120955) JSON.NET now converts multidimensional arrays into an array of arrays in JSON, so the code in the OP will work the same as if you used the code above.

Comment: +1: I'll play with a convert 2d array to a jagged array then.  Maybe that'll do it.  ty.

Comment: this answer is out of date.  see @Timm's below

Comment: @RobertLevy: Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with [Json.Net 4.5 Relase 8 multimensional arrays are supported](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/08/06/json-net-4-5-release-8-multidimensional-array-support-unicode-improvements.aspx).

So your example will work now and produce the following JSON:

```
[ [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2 ] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

when you define an array like you did it isnt a matrix its the same array with two dimensions
that why SerializeObject serialize it as the same array.

Comment: +1... I'm thinking of a matrix and a 2d array as conceptually being the same thing... so I'm finding it hard to follow.  You mean in terms of the underlying .net representation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it works at all. Json.NET doesn't support multidimensional arrays. Use a jagged array instead.

Comment: Can you give any reason why it doesn't support this? Is it because of the ambiguity when converting back from JSON?